# Why redim prevent type mismatch error?

Tags: vba

I have this simplified code where `infosOptions` is a global variable with different types in it :

```
Dim optionsVecteur As Variant
For j = 0 To UBound(infosOptions)
   If infosOptions(j, 11) & " Index" = transac.optionName Then
      optionsVecteur(1) = infosOptions(j, 6)
      optionsVecteur(2) = infosOptions(j, 5)
      optionsVecteur(3) = infosOptions(j, 10)
      Exit For
   End if
End j
```

I have a type mismatch error on `optionsVecteur(1) = infosOptions(j, 6)` but if put `Redim optionsVecteur(3)` it works, why ?

Comment: Because a one dimensional array is not the same thing as a two dimensional array.

Comment: By default `optionsVecteur` is a one dimension array. That's the reason yoo need to `Redim`.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers. So it's not really a 'type' mismatch but a dimension error then !

Comment: Actually, `optionsVecteur` would be a scalar (not a one-dimensional array) if you don't do the `ReDim`, but the `ReDim` changes it from a scalar to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. As pointed out in the comments, you have created a scalar Variant (as in a single variable) and not an array. You need to correct this.

Also, your use of UBound on a multi-dimensional array is liable to fail in other circumstances. It is best practice to use the full definition of UBound to ensure that you actually pick the right limit.

Changes like the below should see your problems resolved:

```
Dim optionsVecteur() As Variant 'This creates an array of variants - But has not dimensioned the array.
ReDim optionsVecteur(1 to 3) as Variant 'This dimensions the array as having 3 elements. You could have just put this in the original line above, but doing this allows you to dynamically change the length of the array of required.

For j = 0 To UBound(infosOptions, 1)'This ensures that VBA considers the upper boundary of the first dimension.
   If infosOptions(j, 11) & " Index" = transac.optionName Then
      optionsVecteur(1) = infosOptions(j, 6)
      optionsVecteur(2) = infosOptions(j, 5)
      optionsVecteur(3) = infosOptions(j, 10)
      Exit For
   End if
Next j 'You want next j not end j.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! "End J" was a typo.